# Appium Android SDK Error: SDK root folder does not exist on the local file system, even after including the system variables for SDK _ root in Mac

Tags: appium

Error: Failed to create session.
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The Android SDK root folder '/rekha/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist on the local file system. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more details
at Object.startWebDriverSession (/Users/rekha/Web/appium-playground/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:68:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
at async Function.newSession (/Users/rekha/Web/appium-playground/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:58:45)
at async Object.exports.remote (/Users/rekha/Web/appium-playground/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:67:22)
at async main (/Users/rekha/Web/appium-playground/index.js:19:20)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
[image]

and I did the following:
**First**
I execute appium-doctor --android to identify the setup errors. In my case, my JAVA_HOME was not valid.
[image]

**SECOND**
Use the command ECHO $SHELL to identify if we use bash, zsh or zshrc. In my case was zsh

[image]

**THIRD**
From the terminal open zshrc using [image: sudo v]
and edit our JAVA_HOME with a valid path and the same for our ANDROID_HOME.
Don't forget to be able to edit, use the command i
Save the changes
[image]

**FOURTH**
Execute the command: exec zsh -l to restart the terminal without restart our mac
**Finally,** execute again appium doctor and execute again your appium.
[image]